# How can I list the methods in a Python 2.5 module?

Tags: python, introspection, python-2.5

I'm trying to use a Python library written in C that has no documentation of any kind. I want to use introspection to at least see what methods and classes are in the modules. Does somebody have a function or library I can use to list the functions (with argument lists) and classes (with methods and member variables) within a module?

I found [this article](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/index.html) about Python introspection, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't apply to Python 2.5. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Here are some things you can do at least:

```
import module

print dir(module) # Find functions of interest.

# For each function of interest:
help(module.interesting_function)
print module.interesting_function.func_defaults
```

Answer (score 12):

Mark Pilgrim's [chapter 4](http://diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/index.html), which you mention, does actually apply just fine to Python 2.5 (and any other recent `2.*` version, thanks to backwards compatibility). Mark doesn't mention `help`, but I see other answers do.

One key bit that nobody (including Mark;-) seems to have mentioned is [inspect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html), an excellent module in Python's standard library that really helps with advanced introspection.

Comment: Link at "chapter 4" is dead.

Answer (score 8):

Just this is pretty good too:

```
import module
help(module)
```

It will print the docstring for the module, then list the contents of the module, printing their docstrings too.

Comment: I can not find any alternative way to get the contents of help, particularly the "PACKAGE CONTENTS" is what I'm looking for. This is in the help text, but none of the other answers provide a way to get it algorithmically.

Comment: ah, found it inside source code for this https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ac317700ce7439e38a8b420218d9a5035bba92ed/Lib/pydoc.py#L733, with pattern of `for importer, modname, ispkg in pkgutil.iter_modules(object.__path__):`

Answer (score 4):

The dir() functions shows all members a module has.