# How do I get list of methods in a Python class?

Tags: python

I want to iterate through the methods in a class, or handle class or instance objects differently based on the methods present. How do I get a list of class methods?

Also see:

- [How can I list the methods in a
  Python 2.5 module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280787/how-can-i-list-the-methods-in-a-python-2-5-module)
- [Looping over
  a Python / IronPython Object
  Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928990/looping-over-a-python-ironpython-object-methods)
- [Finding the methods an
  object has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34439/finding-the-methods-an-object-has)
- [How do I look inside
  a Python object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006169/how-do-i-look-inside-a-python-object)
- [How Do I
  Perform Introspection on an Object in
  Python 2.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546337/how-do-i-perform-introspection-on-an-object-in-python-2-x)
- [How to get a
  complete list of object’s methods and
  attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191010/how-to-get-a-complete-list-of-objects-methods-and-attributes)
- [Finding out which
  functions are available from a class
  instance in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955533/finding-out-which-functions-are-available-from-a-class-instance-in-python)

Answer (score 450, accepted):

An example (listing the methods of the `optparse.OptionParser` class):

```
>>> from optparse import OptionParser
>>> import inspect
#python2
>>> inspect.getmembers(OptionParser, predicate=inspect.ismethod)
[([('__init__', <unbound method OptionParser.__init__>),
...
 ('add_option', <unbound method OptionParser.add_option>),
 ('add_option_group', <unbound method OptionParser.add_option_group>),
 ('add_options', <unbound method OptionParser.add_options>),
 ('check_values', <unbound method OptionParser.check_values>),
 ('destroy', <unbound method OptionParser.destroy>),
 ('disable_interspersed_args',
  <unbound method OptionParser.disable_interspersed_args>),
 ('enable_interspersed_args',
  <unbound method OptionParser.enable_interspersed_args>),
 ('error', <unbound method OptionParser.error>),
 ('exit', <unbound method OptionParser.exit>),
 ('expand_prog_name', <unbound method OptionParser.expand_prog_name>),
 ...
 ]
# python3
>>> inspect.getmembers(OptionParser, predicate=inspect.isfunction)
...
```

Notice that `getmembers` returns a list of 2-tuples. The first item is the name of the member, the second item is the value.

You can also pass an instance to `getmembers`:

```
>>> parser = OptionParser()
>>> inspect.getmembers(parser, predicate=inspect.ismethod)
...
```

Comment: perfect, the predicate part is key, otherwise you get the same thing as __dict__ with the extra meta info. Thanks.

Comment: Will this produce a list of all methods in the class (including ones that are inherited from other classes), or will it only list the methods that are explicitly defined in that class?

Comment: It includes inherited methods.

Comment: This only gives me the base class's methods, not the classes of the derived's.. - Update: this is because all methods in derived were static.

Comment: `getmembers` will only return class attributes defined in the metaclass when the argument is a class.

Comment: `inspect.isroutine` might be a more appropriate predicate; `inspect.ismethod` doesn't work for all objects' methods.

Comment: An interactive console will display the return value of ``inspect.getmembers()``. If you want to display the result from inside a script, you will need to do ``print(inspect.getmembers(...))``.

Comment: If OptionParser inherits some other class then those methods will also get listed

Comment: on python 3.7 at least this doesn't work, you have to instantiate the class

Comment: In Python 3 there is no such thing as an unbound method. In 3.7, this works with the class: `inspect.getmembers(OptionsParser, predicate=inspect.isfunction)`

Answer (score 294):

There is the `dir(theobject)` method to list all the fields and methods of your object (as a tuple) and the inspect module (as codeape write) to list the fields and methods with their doc (in """).

Because everything (even fields) might be called in Python, I'm not sure there is a built-in function to list only methods. You might want to try if the *object* you get through `dir` is [callable](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#callable) or not.

Answer (score 222):

Python 3.x answer without external libraries

```
method_list = [func for func in dir(Foo) if callable(getattr(Foo, func))]
```

dunder-excluded result:

```
method_list = [func for func in dir(Foo) if callable(getattr(Foo, func)) and not func.startswith("__")]
```

Comment: Cool, but it does not include getter-setter methods decorated with `@property` and `@property.setter`

Comment: this what worked with objects.

Answer (score 64):

Say you want to know all methods associated with list class
Just Type The following

```
 print (dir(list))
```

Above will give you all methods of list class

Comment: `print([ m for m in dir(my_class) if not m.startswith('__')])`

Answer (score 39):

Try the property `__dict__`.

Comment: I think you mean __dict__. But that lists the attributes of the instance, not the methods.

Comment: …that didn't work for me either. Having consulted the Markdown syntax, I think I mean \_\_dict\_\_.

Comment: @me_and you're probably doing "self.__dict__" or, more generically, calling the instance version of `__dict__`. However classes have a `__dict__` too and that should display the class methods :)

Answer (score 33):

you can also import the FunctionType from types and test it with the `class.__dict__`:

```py
from types import FunctionType

class Foo:
    def bar(self): pass
    def baz(self): pass

def methods(cls):
    return [x for x, y in cls.__dict__.items() if type(y) == FunctionType]

methods(Foo)  # ['bar', 'baz']
```

Comment: This worked well for me.  I did add `and not x.startswith('_')` to the end of the list comprehension for my use to ignore `__init__`'s and private methods.

Comment: You can get rid of the `import` of `FunctionType` by using a throwaway lambda with `type()`: `type(lambda:0)`

Comment: `isinstance` would be the better than `type(y) == FunctionType` here.

Comment: for callable function you can just replace `x` in the start to `y` (use `[y for x, y in cls.__dict__.items() if type(y) == FunctionType]`)

Comment: this doesn't work with objects, only classes, otherwise `__dict__.items()` won't have any moethods

Answer (score 29):

You can list all methods in a python class by using the following code

```
dir(className)
```

This will return a list of all the names of the methods in the class

Comment: This also reports non-method class attributes.

Answer (score 15):

Note that you need to consider whether you want methods from base classes which are inherited (but not overridden) included in the result. The `dir()` and `inspect.getmembers()` operations do include base class methods, but use of the `__dict__` attribute does not.

Answer (score 10):

If your method is a "regular" method and not a `staticmethod`, `classmethod` etc.
There is a little hack I came up with -

```py
for k, v in your_class.__dict__.items():
    if "function" in str(v):
        print(k)
```

This can be extended to other type of methods by changing "function" in the `if` condition correspondingly.
Tested in Python 2.7 and Python 3.5.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted... it did actually solve the problem I was having.

Comment: `if isinstance(v, types.FunctionTypes)` would be cleaner. You can also extend this to check for attributes of type `classmethod` and `staticmethod`.

Comment: Typo in what chepner recommended. Use `if isinstance(v, types.FunctionType)`

Answer (score 10):

Try
`print(help(ClassName))`
It prints out methods of the class

Comment: Amazing! I learnt something new. Unfortunately this does not list the `staticmethod`s of a class: I wonder if that's even possible.

Answer (score 8):

I just keep this there, because **top rated answers are not clear**.

This is simple test with not usual class based on Enum.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys, inspect
from enum import Enum

class my_enum(Enum):
    """Enum base class my_enum"""
    M_ONE = -1
    ZERO = 0
    ONE = 1
    TWO = 2
    THREE = 3

    def is_natural(self):
            return (self.value > 0)
    def is_negative(self):
            return (self.value < 0)

def is_clean_name(name):
    return not name.startswith('_') and not name.endswith('_')
def clean_names(lst):
    return [ n for n in lst if is_clean_name(n) ]
def get_items(cls,lst):
    try:
            res = [ getattr(cls,n) for n in lst ]
    except Exception as e:
            res = (Exception, type(e), e)
            pass
    return res


print( sys.version )

dir_res = clean_names( dir(my_enum) )
inspect_res = clean_names( [ x[0] for x in inspect.getmembers(my_enum) ] )
dict_res = clean_names( my_enum.__dict__.keys() )

print( '## names ##' )
print( dir_res )
print( inspect_res )
print( dict_res )

print( '## items ##' )
print( get_items(my_enum,dir_res) )
print( get_items(my_enum,inspect_res) )
print( get_items(my_enum,dict_res) )
```

And this is output results.

```
3.7.7 (default, Mar 10 2020, 13:18:53) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20200306]
## names ##
['M_ONE', 'ONE', 'THREE', 'TWO', 'ZERO']
['M_ONE', 'ONE', 'THREE', 'TWO', 'ZERO', 'name', 'value']
['is_natural', 'is_negative', 'M_ONE', 'ZERO', 'ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE']
## items ##
[<my_enum.M_ONE: -1>, <my_enum.ONE: 1>, <my_enum.THREE: 3>, <my_enum.TWO: 2>, <my_enum.ZERO: 0>]
(<class 'Exception'>, <class 'AttributeError'>, AttributeError('name'))
[<function my_enum.is_natural at 0xb78a1fa4>, <function my_enum.is_negative at 0xb78ae854>, <my_enum.M_ONE: -1>, <my_enum.ZERO: 0>, <my_enum.ONE: 1>, <my_enum.TWO: 2>, <my_enum.THREE: 3>]
```

So what we have:

- `dir` provide not complete data
- `inspect.getmembers` provide not complete data and provide internal keys that are not accessible with `getattr()`
- `__dict__.keys()` provide **complete and reliable result**

Why are votes so erroneous? And where i'm wrong? And where wrong other people which answers have so low votes?

Answer (score 7):

This also works:

In `mymodule.py`:

```
def foo(x):
   return 'foo'
def bar():
   return 'bar'
```

In another file:

```
import inspect
import mymodule
method_list = [ func[0] for func in inspect.getmembers(mymodule, predicate=inspect.isroutine) if callable(getattr(mymodule, func[0])) ]
```

Output:

> ['foo', 'bar']

From the Python docs:

```
inspect.isroutine(object)
```

> Return true if the object is a user-defined or built-in function or method.

Answer (score 6):

There's this approach:

```py
[getattr(obj, m) for m in dir(obj) if not m.startswith('__')]
```

When dealing with a class **instance**, perhaps it'd be better to return a list with the method references instead of just names¹. If that's your goal, as well as

1. Using no `import`
2. Excluding private methods (e.g. `__init__`) from the list

It may be of use. You might also want to assure it's `callable(getattr(obj, m))`, since `dir` returns all attributes within `obj`, not just methods.

In a nutshell, for a class like

```py
class Ghost:
    def boo(self, who):
        return f'Who you gonna call? {who}'
```

We could check instance retrieval with

```
>>> g = Ghost()
>>> methods = [getattr(g, m) for m in dir(g) if not m.startswith('__')]
>>> print(methods)
[<bound method Ghost.boo of <__main__.Ghost object at ...>>]
```

So you can call it right away:

```py
>>> for method in methods:
...     print(method('GHOSTBUSTERS'))
...
Who you gonna call? GHOSTBUSTERS
```

¹ An use case:

I used this for *unit testing*. Had a class where all methods performed variations of the same process - which led to lengthy tests, each only a tweak away from the others. [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) was a far away dream.

Thought I should have a single test for all methods, so I made the above iteration.

Although I realized I should instead refactor *the code itself* to be DRY-compliant anyway... this may still serve a random nitpicky soul in the future.

Answer (score 3):

```
def find_defining_class(obj, meth_name):
    for ty in type(obj).mro():
        if meth_name in ty.__dict__:
            return ty
```

So

```
print find_defining_class(car, 'speedometer')
```

*Think Python page 210*

Comment: Indentation of 5? Capitalizing keywords? Non-pep8-style spacing?

Comment: Not once the coding convention nazis got to it!

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 3):

```
methods = [(func, getattr(o, func)) for func in dir(o) if callable(getattr(o, func))]
```

gives an identical list as

```
methods = inspect.getmembers(o, predicate=inspect.ismethod)
```

does.

Comment: There's a subtle distinction this will overlook (though perhaps not one you would care about, depending on the use case): this will count callable instance attributes as methods. Methods are *class* attributes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a function which I have created.

```py
def method_finder(classname):

    non_magic_class = []

    class_methods = dir(classname)

    for m in class_methods:

        if m.startswith('__'):

            continue

        else:

            non_magic_class.append(m)

    return non_magic_class




method_finder(list)
```

Output:

```
['append',
 'clear',
 'copy',
 'count',
 'extend',
 'index',
 'insert',
 'pop',
 'remove',
 'reverse',
 'sort']
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but just wrote this function and will leave it here is case someone stumbles looking for an answer:

```
def classMethods(the_class,class_only=False,instance_only=False,exclude_internal=True):

    def acceptMethod(tup):
        #internal function that analyzes the tuples returned by getmembers tup[1] is the 
        #actual member object
        is_method = inspect.ismethod(tup[1])
        if is_method:
            bound_to = tup[1].im_self
            internal = tup[1].im_func.func_name[:2] == '__' and tup[1].im_func.func_name[-2:] == '__'
            if internal and exclude_internal:
                include = False
            else:
                include = (bound_to == the_class and not instance_only) or (bound_to == None and not class_only)
        else:
            include = False
        return include
    #uses filter to return results according to internal function and arguments
    return filter(acceptMethod,inspect.getmembers(the_class))
```

Comment: This code does not do what it is intended as published. Giving class_only or instance_only will result in empty list.

Answer (score 1):

use inspect.ismethod and dir and getattr

```
 import inspect
 class ClassWithMethods:
    
    def method1(self):
        print('method1')
    def method2(self):
        print('method2')

obj=ClassWithMethods()

method_names = [attr for attr in dir(obj) if inspect.ismethod(getattr(obj,attr))

print(method_names)
```

output:

```
[[('method1', <bound method ClassWithMethods.method1 of <__main__.ClassWithMethods object at 0x00000266779AF388>>), ('method2', <bound method ClassWithMethods.method2 of <__main__.ClassWithMethods object at 0x00000266779AF388>>)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me.

I've encountered this problem while writing pytests.

The only work-around I found was to:

1- create another directory and place all my .py files there

2- create a separate directory for my pytests and then importing the classes I'm interested in

This allowed me to get up-to-dated methods within the class - you can change the method names and then use `print(dir(class))` to confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

For my use case, I needed to distinguish between class methods, static methods, properties, and instance methods. The inspect module confuses the issue a bit (particularly with class methods and instance methods), so I used `vars` based on a comment on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61724073/2364215). The basic gist is to use `vars` to get the `__dict__` attribute of the class, then filter based on various `isinstance` checks. For instance methods, I check that it is `callable` and not a class method. One caveat: this approach of using [`vars` (or `__dict__` for that matter) won't work with `__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars). Using Python 3.6.9 (because it's what the Docker image I'm using as my interpreter has):

```py
class MethodAnalyzer:

    class_under_test = None

    @classmethod
    def get_static_methods(cls):
        if cls.class_under_test:
            return {
                k for k, v in vars(cls.class_under_test).items()
                if isinstance(v, staticmethod)
            }
        return {}

    @classmethod
    def get_class_methods(cls):
        if cls.class_under_test:
            return {
                k for k, v in vars(cls.class_under_test).items()
                if isinstance(v, classmethod)
            }
        return {}

    @classmethod
    def get_instance_methods(cls):
        if cls.class_under_test:
            return {
                k for k, v in vars(cls.class_under_test).items()
                if callable(v) and not isinstance(v, classmethod)
            }
        return {}

    @classmethod
    def get_properties(cls):
        if cls.class_under_test:
            return {
                k for k, v in vars(cls.class_under_test).items()
                if isinstance(v, property)
            }
        return {}
```

To see it in action, I created this little test class:

```py
class Foo:

    @staticmethod
    def bar(baz):
        print(baz)

    @property
    def bleep(self):
        return 'bloop'

    @classmethod
    def bork(cls):
        return cls.__name__

    def flank(self):
        return 'on your six'
```

then did:

```py
MethodAnalyzer.class_under_test = Foo
print(MethodAnalyzer.get_instance_methods())
print(MethodAnalyzer.get_class_methods())
print(MethodAnalyzer.get_static_methods())
print(MethodAnalyzer.get_properties())
```

which output

```
{'flank'}
{'bork'}
{'bar'}
{'bleep'}
```

In this example I'm discarding the actual methods, but if you needed to keep them you could just use a dict comprehension instead of a set comprehension:

```py
{
    k, v for k, v in vars(cls.class_under_test).items()
    if callable(v) and not isinstance(v, classmethod)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is just an observation. "encode" seems to be a method for string objects

```
str_1 = 'a'
str_1.encode('utf-8')
>>> b'a'
```

However, if str1 is inspected for methods, an empty list is returned

```
inspect.getmember(str_1, predicate=inspect.ismethod)
>>> []
```

So, maybe I am wrong, but the issue seems to be not simple.

Comment: `'a'` is an object, whose type is `str`. You can see this by running `type('a')`. `inspect.getmember()` takes a type parameter, so you need to call `inspect.getmember(str)` to see what you expect.

Answer (score -1):

To produce a list of methods put the name of the method in a list without the usual parenthesis. Remove the name and attach the parenthesis and that calls the method.

```
    def methodA():
        print("@ MethodA")

    def methodB():
        print("@ methodB")

    a = []
    a.append(methodA)
    a.append(methodB)
    for item in a:
        item()
```

Answer (score -1):

Just like this

```py
pprint.pprint([x for x in dir(list) if not x.startswith("_")])
```

Comment: That will also list attributes

Answer (score -2):

```
class CPerson:
    def __init__(self, age):
        self._age = age

    def run(self):
        pass

    @property
    def age(self): return self._age

    @staticmethod
    def my_static_method(): print("Life is short, you need Python")

    @classmethod
    def say(cls, msg): return msg


test_class = CPerson
# print(dir(test_class))  # list all the fields and methods of your object
print([(name, t) for name, t in test_class.__dict__.items() if type(t).__name__ == 'function' and not name.startswith('__')])
print([(name, t) for name, t in test_class.__dict__.items() if type(t).__name__ != 'function' and not name.startswith('__')])
```

**output**

```
[('run', <function CPerson.run at 0x0000000002AD3268>)]
[('age', <property object at 0x0000000002368688>), ('my_static_method', <staticmethod object at 0x0000000002ACBD68>), ('say', <classmethod object at 0x0000000002ACF0B8>)]
```

Answer (score -6):

If you want to list only methods of a python class

```
import numpy as np
print(np.random.__all__)
```

Comment: That's a module, not a class.

Comment: @Aran-Fey It is applied for every class, __all__ is exist in every class

Comment: No, it doesn't. It doesn't even exist in all *modules*.