# Listing all instance of a class

Tags: python, class, python-2.7

I wrote a Python module, with several classes that inherit from a single class called `MasterBlock`.
I want to import this module in a script, create several instances of these classes, and then get a list of all the existing instances of all the childrens of this `MasterBlock` class. I found some solutions with `vars()['Blocks.MasterBlock'].__subclasses__()` but as the instances I have are child of child of `MasterBlock`, it doesn't work.

Here is some example code:

Module:

```
Class MasterBlock:
    def main(self):
        pass
Class RandomA(MasterBlock):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    # inherit the main function
Class AnotherRandom(MasterBlock):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    # inherit the main function
```

Script:

```
import module
a=module.RandomA()
b=module.AnotherRandom()
c=module.AnotherRandom()
# here I need to get list_of_instances=[a,b,c]
```

Th ultimate goal is to be able to do:

```
for instance in list_of_instances:
    instance.main()
```

Comment: You can combine a solution of [Listing all user methods of a class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911281/how-do-i-get-list-of-methods-in-a-python-class) and [Calling a class method by string representation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name-in-python).

Comment: @Torxed How would this work? The question asks for a list of _instances_, not _attributes_.

Comment: Using global state like this is generally a bad idea. It's probably better to just keep track of the `[a, b, c]` list as you create `a`, `b`, and `c`.

Comment: @user2357112 How do you want to keep track of this? I would say that the _automatic_ tracking that the question asks for is robust.

Comment: @EOL: `list_of_instances = [a, b, c]`?

Comment: @user2357112 This is dangerous (error prone), in general: what if someone modifies the code and does not know that/whether `list_of_instances` should be updated? The idea behind the question is that this bookkeeping be automatic, so as to avoid errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a `__new__()` method as shown below to your base class which keeps track of all instances created in a class variable, you could make the process more-or-less automatic and not have to remember to call something in the `__init__()` of each subclass.

```
class MasterBlock(object):
    instances = []
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super(MasterBlock, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        instance.instances.append(instance)
        return instance

    def main(self):
        print('in main of', self.__class__.__name__)  # for testing purposes

class RandomA(MasterBlock):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    # inherit the main function

class AnotherRandom(RandomA):  # works for sub-subclasses, too
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    # inherit the main function

a=RandomA()
b=AnotherRandom()
c=AnotherRandom()

for instance in MasterBlock.instances:
    instance.main()
```

Output:

```
in main of RandomA
in main of AnotherRandom
in main of AnotherRandom
```

Comment: Well, I have too much good answers to this question! Thanks a lot, I did'nt know about `__new__()` and it is exactly what I needed here!

Comment: You're welcome. Writing a class `__new__()` method isn't necessary very often, but knowing that it's available and when it's called during the creation of instances (if defined) can be helpful in certain situations, as illustrated. This will also work if you ever define sub-subclasses, btw.

Answer (score 2):

What about adding a class variable, that contains all the instances of `MasterBlock`? You can record them with:

```
Class MasterBlock(object):

    all_instances = []  # All instances of MasterBlock

    def __init__(self,…):
        …
        self.all_instances.append(self)  # Not added if an exception is raised before
```

You get all the instances of `MasterBlock` with `MasterBlock.all_instances` (or `instance.all_instances`).

This works if all base classes call the `__init__` of the master class (either implicitly through inheritance or explicitly through the usual `super()` call).

Comment: I would put `all_instances` inside the class as a class variable.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way of doing that using a class variable:

```
class MasterBlock(object):
    instances = []
    def __init__(self):
        self.instances.append(self)
    def main(self):
        print "I am", self

class RandomA(MasterBlock):
    def __init__(self):
        super(RandomA, self).__init__()
        # other init...

class AnotherRandom(MasterBlock):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AnotherRandom, self).__init__()
        # other init...


a = RandomA()
b = AnotherRandom()
c = AnotherRandom()
# here I need to get list_of_instances=[a,b,c]

for instance in MasterBlock.instances:
    instance.main()
```

(you can make it simpler if you don't need `__init__` in the subclasses)

output:

```
I am <__main__.RandomA object at 0x7faa46683610>
I am <__main__.AnotherRandom object at 0x7faa46683650>
I am <__main__.AnotherRandom object at 0x7faa46683690>
```

Comment: This looks exactly like my answer… Why add this? In my eyes, this mostly adds noise and should be deleted. If you want to make it explicit how to use `super()`, you can do so either in a comment instead, or you can even edit my answer.

Comment: because I wrote it before you posted your answer so, eh, might as well post it anyway :)

Comment: You should have reloaded the page: my answer came 6–3 minutes before yours. :) StackOverflow displays a banner, when a new answer appears. I do think that your answer is good, but it is essentially a duplicate, so I would delete it so as to not waste the time of those who read it (they won't gain much new information).

Comment: Well that is a very clear and complete answer, so I will take it! Thank you very much!