# C#: reflection-like mechanism into python file (get functions, parameters etc)

Tags: c#, python, reflection, documentation

From a C# program, I want to examine a given python file for the functions it offers. If possible, I also want to get metainformation about each function and parameter, like a description.

I can control both the C# side and the Python side.

How can I achieve that?

(As for the use case: I am going to write a dispatcher function in Python that the C# program can call inside the python script to execute a specific function, given the required arguments.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never tried this. But think you could use a combination of the module `optparse` (Taken from [How do I get list of methods in a Python class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911281/how-do-i-get-list-of-methods-in-a-python-class)):

```
from optparse import OptionParser
import inspect
inspect.getmembers(OptionParser, predicate=inspect.ismethod)
```

With `function.__doc__` to get the documentation from the method like

```
def factorial(x):
    '''int f(int x); returns the factorial of an integer number'''
    #code here

>>> factorial.__doc__
'int f(int x); returns the factorial of an integer number'
```

Use the first part (`int f(int x);`) as the description of what parameters it needs and returns (You could take this part just taking the string until first semicolon)

And use `getattr` to call the function (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
getattr(myObject, 'factorial', '3')()
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you. I would like to do this from the C# side though, not python-to-python.

Comment: Well in your C# code should have some code like `getFunctions()` which will call the `optparser` in your python code, then it will return the corresponding part of the `__doc__` string to the C# process do what you need and then use something like `callFunction(args)` which will call `getattr` in python process. If i undestood you right that's what you want

Comment: Yes, that also fulfuills my requirements. Coming from the C# side, I would prefer the logic there, but this is also fine. (Plus, in this case I would have to call into the Python code already when examining it, in the other case I only have to do that at runtime. Those are 2 different scenarios in my case.)

Comment: I think you could open python file as text from C# code and look for the triple-quoted string or just look for the `def func(param)` (Lines starting with "def"), but I don't think it's scalable neither a good practice