# Python Introspection: How do I find out what functions can be applied to instances of classes

Tags: python, introspection

For example: air_passengers.rolling_window(window = 12).mean().plot()

How do I find out that mean() can be applied to a rolling_window()? How do I find out that plot() can be applied to a mean()?

Is there something equivalent to **doc** for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get list of methods in a Python class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911281/how-do-i-get-list-of-methods-in-a-python-class)

Comment: I want to know what functions can be applied rather than the list of methods of the class  [I'm probably using the wrong term, but e.g mean() is not a method of rolling_window [i think?], but can be applied]

Comment: Well, not really. It is probably like this. `air_passengers` is an object of a class that has a method `rolling_window()`. This returns an object of a class that has a method `mean()`, which then again returns an object of a class that has a method `plot()`. Hope everything is unclear, now.

Answer (score 0):

you can use dir(object), which give all associated attributes of a object

```
print(dir(air_passengers.rolling_window(window = 12)))
```