# Function to call functions within a class

Tags: python, python-3.6

I have an issue, I'd like to have a function that calls or executes all functions inside a class.

```
class example:
    def foo(self):
        print("hi")
    def bar(self):
        print("hello")
    def all(self):
        self.foo()
        self.bar()
```

Is there any better way to do this? Since my class has around 20 functions and I want just one function to call all of them.
Thanks

Comment: should be possible iterate over all the methods but would not be pretty or better

Comment: You can use inspection, ugly but will work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911281/how-do-i-get-list-of-methods-in-a-python-class

Comment: instead of properly trying to check the type you can try to invoke each member. Might have few issues with static or class methods if any

Answer (score 1):

See [How do I get list of methods in a Python class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911281/how-do-i-get-list-of-methods-in-a-python-class) to how enlist method with inspect or dir

While all are ugly, inspection is the prefered methods.
You can invoke all the methods of an object via inspect

```
import inspect

class A:
    def h(self):
        print ('hellow')

    def all(self):


        for name, f in inspect.getmembers(self, predicate=inspect.ismethod):

            if name != 'all' and not name.startswith('_'):
               f()


a = A()
a.all()
```

If prefer dir you can try - catch getattr(self, attr)()

```
for attr in dir(self):
   try: 
      getattr(self, attr)()
   except Exception:
      pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I put this together and tested it and it seems to work and does not need any libraries and follows your original intent:

```
class example:
    def __init__(self):
        n = self.__class__.__name__
        self.method_list = [func for func in dir(eval(n)) \
                            if callable(getattr(eval(n), func)) \
                            and func[0]!='_' \
                            and func!='run_all']
    def foo(self):
        print("hi")
    def bar(self):
        print("hello")
    def run_all(self):
        for m in self.method_list:
            runstring = 'self.' + m + '()'
            eval(runstring)
```

Using it:

```
>> a = example()
>> a.run_all()
hello
hi
```

`all` is a Python command so I renamed your method to `run_all`.

`func!='run_all'` was necessary so you don't get a nasty recursion situation happening.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39061905/4288043) lets you list the methods, I restricted it just so that no private methods get listed.

`self.__class__.__name__` gets the name of your class

Comment: Thanks, the only problem is that it works when the function returns a print. However in my class each function returns a list of elements that with this code does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not sure if that's the best way to do it, i suggest the following

```
class AClass():

    def my_method_1(self):
        print('inside method 1')

    def my_method_2(self):
        print('inside method 2')

def run_my_methods():
    executor = AClass()
    all_methods = dir(executor)
    #separate out the special functions like '__call__', ...
    my_methods = [method for method in all_methods if not '__' in method]  
    for method in my_methods:
        eval('executor.%s()'%method)

run_my_methods()
```

Output is

```
inside method 1 
inside method 2
```