# What would be better way if any to store list of methods that would be easily accessible?

Tags: python, oop

I have a class that has multiple methods and I want to store all of the available methods that would be easily accessible in example would be something like this

```py
class Methods:
    def foo(self, a):
        return f'hello {a}' 


    def bar(self, b):
        return f'hello {b}'

    def methods_dict(self, var, **kwargs):
        dic = {
            'me' : self.foo(var),
            'be': self.bar(var)
        }
    return dic
```

But on runtime my `methods_dict()` method will execute both of the methods inside of it's dictionary.
One one hand I'm planing to store only strings in there and it's really easily accessible, on the other hand i probably would not need to access all of the available methods at once.

Any suggestions ?

I am planning to use those methods as follows

```
class InheritMethods(Methods):
        def __init__(self, method_name):
            self.method_name = method_name

        def add_to_list(self, input):
            arr = []
            arr.append(self.method_dicts(input)[self.method_name]
            return arr
```

To clear things up, I am gonna call specific method based on input name, so basically `input == method_name`
I could do conditional statements like `if input == 'foo': do somethings..`, but if i end up having a lot of methods, my code is going to be a mess, so i assume(!) that would not be a great idea

Comment: You've just invented a problem for yourself. I can't see any reason for this

Comment: what is your goal of that methods_dict?

Comment: Can you give an example of how you plan to use `methods_dict`? I don't understand the end goal exactly.

Comment: Check out [properties](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property).

Comment: you can do `lambda _: self.foo(var)`, or just return `self.foo`?

Comment: @LaurensKoppenol at this point, you could just go with {'foo': foo}.

Comment: Another idea would be to fall back on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911281/how-do-i-get-list-of-methods-in-a-python-class).

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem no you can't, `foo` is a class' method and not in scope from `methods_dict`, you need `{'foo': self.foo}`

Comment: @LaurensKoppenol my bad, I've misread the post. Maybe `functools.partial` would be appropriate, if anything.

Comment: if there would be optionally more arguments that would be a great idea

Comment: @LaurensKoppenol I inherit this class in another class and there i input an instance which would be the name of a method, i'll update my question i guess

Comment: Please do update your question. It sounds like there could be an overall improvement!

Comment: @LaurensKoppenol I have updated it, hopefully that clears things up

Comment: What is the point of `IneritMethods`? Why do both `__init__` and `add_to_list` take a `method_name` as an argument, when `self.method_name` appears to be ignored? Given `Methods` with *just* the methods `foo` and `bar`, what exactly do you need?

Comment: @chepner you are right, i was writing code on the go, i removed useless parameter in add_to_list method and just added self.method_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get what you want with the following. Your exact usecase is still not clear. Please respond if I am heading in the wrong direction.

Using `self.__getattribute__()` you can get a function by name. Of course you would have to catch exceptions etc.

```
class Methods:
    def foo(self, a):
        return f'hello {a}' 

    def bar(self, b):
        return f'hello {b}'

class InheritMethods(Methods):
    def __init__(self, method_name):
        self.method_name = method_name

    def add_to_list(self, method_name, input):
        method = getattr(self, method_name)
        result = method(input)
        return [result]

class InheritSingleMethod(Methods):
    def __init__(self, method_name):
        self.add_to_list = self.getattr(self, method_name)
```

**Output**

```
# Any method version
inherit_methods = InheritMethods('a')  # < no use for that argument right?
inherit_methods.add_to_list('foo', 'laurens')
> ['hello laurens']

# Single method version
inherit_single_method = InheritSingleMethod('foo')
inherit_single_method.add_to_list('laurens')
> 'hello laurens'
```

Comment: oh lord, i was thinking of this solution using getattr(), but that was not the case.
That works ! Thank you (:

Comment: actually, a little improvement to your code, we can pass ```self.method_name``` instead of creating extra parameter in ```add_to_list()```  Since we are instantiating method_name anyways

Comment: Unless you refer to Guido van Rossum, the lord is not good at python. He is not too well with snakes in general actually.

Comment: if you only want to use 1 single function in `add_to_list`, check out `InheritSingleMethod` above!

Comment: why are you using `self.__getattribute__(method_name)` instead of just `getattr(self, method_name)`?  the latter seems much less magical!

Comment: @SamMason i was attemtping getattr() but i was getting an error :O

Comment: @SamMason you are right actually, but it has to be getattr(self, self.method_name) if taking method_name and that's where i got my error

Comment: cool, didnt know that one worked for classes as well. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is access a method of `Methods` given the name in a `str`, use `getattr`:

```
name = input()
m = Methods()
getattr(m, name)("bob")
```