# How to get user-defined methods name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I'm trying to get all the user-defined methods name from a class, ex:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, param1, param2):
        pass

    def one_method(self):
        pass

    def __repr__(self):
        pass

    def __str__(self):
        pass

    def __my_method_no_2(self, param2):
        pass

    def _my_method_no_3(self):
        pass
```

so far I have come to the following approach:

```
import inspect 

[name for name, _ in inspect.getmembers(MyClass, inspect.isroutine)
 if name not in {'__init_subclass__', '__subclasshook__'} and 
 getattr(MyClass, name).__qualname__.startswith(MyClass.__name__)]
```

output:

```
['_MyClass__my_method_no_2',
 '__init__',
 '__repr__',
 '__str__',
 '_my_method_no_3',
 'one_method']
```

this is the expected output, but this looks "ugly" and not even sure if is the right approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911281/how-do-i-get-list-of-methods-in-a-python-class), but using `__dict__` instead of `dir`.

Every python objects has a `__dict__` attribute containing names of all attributes. Relevant docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__)

The idea is: get a list of attributes from `__dict__` and filter out everything non-callable

```
[attr for attr in  MyClass.__dict__ if callable(getattr(MyClass, attr))]
```

Matches with your output

Answer (score 2):

In `Python 3.x`, you can use [dir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) without [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#module-inspect) or any external libraries:

```
method_list = [func for func in dir(Foo) if callable(getattr(Foo, func))]
```

To handle every method that you newly define in your class and override in your class, Try this:

```
class MyClass:
    li = []
    def __init__(self, param1, param2):
        pass

    def one_method(self):
        pass

    def __repr__(self):
        pass

    def __str__(self):
        pass

    def __my_method_no_2(self, param2):
        pass

    def _my_method_no_3(self):
        pass


print([func for func in dir(MyClass) if callable(getattr(MyClass, func)) and func in MyClass.__dict__])
```

Outputs:

```
['_MyClass__my_method_no_2', '__init__', '__repr__', '__str__', '_my_method_no_3', 'one_method']
```