# How to list all staticmethods of a python class

Tags: python, python-3.x, memoization, joblib

I have a class somewhat like following:

```py
from joblib import Memory
import time


def find_static_methods(cls):
    # to be implemented
    pass


class A:

    def __init__(self, cache_path: str):
        self._memory = Memory(cache_path, verbose=0)
        self._methods = {}
        for name, method in find_static_methods(A):
            self._methods[name] = self._memory.cache(method)

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        if item in self._methods:
            return self._methods[item]
        return super(A, self).__getattribute__(item)

    @staticmethod
    def method1(a: int, b: int):
        time.sleep(3)
        return a + b
```

I'm trying to memoize `method1` using `joblib.Memory`. But I don't know the `cache_path` in advance. Please help me with the implementation of `find_static_methods` here.

Comment: Do you care about potentially inherited methods?

Comment: anyway, all staticmethods would be something like `[attr for attr in vars(A).values() if isinstance(attr, staticmethod)]` if you dont' care about inherited methods. If you do, you'll have to check the attributes of all classes in the method resolution order.

Comment: Thanks let me try this one!

Comment: I am also not sure if `Memory.cache` will work with `staticmethod` objects, you might have to use the underlying function, available at `attr.__func__`

Comment: I was about to ask the same as I got an error from joblib saying `staticmethod` objects are not callable.

Comment: Thanks a lot @juanpa.arrivillaga! `attr.__func__` solved the problem :)

Comment: Not sure whether this works: I tried it on QtCore.QObject (PyQt5) and it said that it had no staticmethods, which is not the case. The PyQt5 package may be doing strange things though.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way:

```
A_attrs = A.__dict__
for k, v in A_attrs.items():
    if isinstance(v, staticmethod):
        print(k)
```

Comment: Not sure whether this works: I tried it on `QtCore.QObject` (PyQt5) and it said that it had no `staticmethod`s, which is not the case. The PyQt5 package may be doing strange things though.

Comment: it works with Class A