# How to dynamically invoke a staticmethod without creating an instance object

Tags: python, static-methods

Code similar to this is typically used to dynamically create a class object and call an instance method, but how can I dynamically call a @staticmethod in a class without constructing an instance?
This post is useful but doesn't show invocation: [How to list all staticmethods of a python class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61724073/how-to-list-all-staticmethods-of-a-python-class)

```
module = __import__('MyClass')
my_class = getattr(module, 'MyClass')    # this invokes constructor
result = my_class().my_static_method()
```

Comment: I don't understand... `getattr(module, 'MyClass').my_static_method()` doesn't work? or `module.MyClass.my_static_method()`

Comment: Static methods, by definition, mustn't require an instance of the class. `MyClass.static_method()` - the `@staticmethod` decorator strips the `self` argument if it is provided `MyClass().static_method()`

Comment: @Andrej Kesely That works! Thanks. I'm not sure why I was previously invoking the constructor.

Comment: 'Dynamically invoke a static method' is a contradiction in terms.

Comment: `staticmethod` doesn't "strip" anything. Its `__get__` method always returns the underlying function, never a `method` object that would be responsible for passing an implicit argument to the underlying function when called.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html provides a good explanation of how descriptors work, including how `staticmethod` actually works.