# How do i list available datasets loaders in sklearn to see all list of available function

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to list available datasets loaders after importing datasets module from sklearn to see a list of available function but it gives me an error :

```
from sklearn import datasets

datasets.load_

AttributeError: module 'sklearn.datasets' has no attribute 'load_'
```

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/index.html

Comment: Thanks @TrentonMcKinney. Is it possible to list them in notebook? I am trying to list them in it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get list of methods in a Python class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911281/how-do-i-get-list-of-methods-in-a-python-class). `dir(datasets)` or `import inspect` then `inspect.getmembers(datasets, predicate=inspect.isfunction)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @TrentonMcKinney. Yes I tried it and this is what i was looking for. Appreciate it.