# Getting functions from Python file as passable objects

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Python file from which I would like to get all functions. I want to pass these functions to another file in order to collect data about these functions.
For Example.py:

```
class Example:

    def method_to_extract(name: str) -> none:
        print(name)
```

I want to extract this method as an object through the file name and pass it as an argument to another function, like

```
func = magic_method(Example.py) # returns method_to_extract as a callable object
collect_data(func)
```

Is this possible? So far, I have only been able to extract the names of functions as strings. However, that does not help me, as I want to collect data about the functions like the number of arguments, type hints, and more, and therefore need to be able to access the entire function.
I also tried getting the function using `func = getattr(class, funcname)`, but I wasn't able to pass `func` as a parameter and extract the data I need.

Comment: You'll need to actually import `Example.py` before being able to use `getattr()` or similar methods. If you need to you can do imports dynamically with [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html)

Comment: it would be easier if you want to extract the functions from the class instead of the file

Comment: How does this work if I want the file name to be a variable?

Comment: How would it work for extracting functions from a class instead of a file?

Comment: @AvenDesta Not really, both are easy to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of 3 solutions, dependant on your particular needs.

1. Simplest one: don't use classes, just global functions:

   ```py
   # file1.py
   def method_to_extract(name):
       print(name)
   ```

   And then in another file just import and use it:

   ```py
   # file2.py
   from file2 import method_to_extract
   method_to_extract()
   ```
2. In case you especially want to use methods inside of a class, you can make them static with `@staticmethod` decorator:

   ```py
   # file1.py
   class Example:
       @staticmethod
       def method_to_extract(name):
           print(name)
   ```

   And then in another file just import and use it:

   ```py
   # file2.py
   from file2 import Example
   Example.method_to_extract()
   ```

   More on staticmetod decorator here: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/staticmethod
3. Of course, not all of your methods can be static. Then you just have to create an instance of the class and then use its methods:

   ```py
   # file1.py
   class Example:
       def method_to_extract(name):
           print(name)
   ```

   And then in another file just import and use it:

   ```py
   # file2.py
   from file2 import Example
   instance = Example()
   instance.method_to_extract()
   ```

Basically, the above three approaches are in general only possible ways of accessing some particular function or method in python and the fact of exporting them to another file doesn't change a thing.

Comment: Thank you! But if I don't want the code to be static, rather handle any type of file given to it and extract data for the functions contained in that file, I can't use any of these solutions, or am I missing something here?
Basically I want to be able to extract all methods from any python file and collect data about these methods. If you consider that I may not even know what is in the files I want to evaluate, this solution does not really work, unless I'm missing something here.

Comment: I would say it's a very weird use case. Maybe you will find something helpful here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911281/how-do-i-get-list-of-methods-in-a-python-class

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```py
from Example import Example.method_to_extract as mte
collect_data(mte)
```

The code you show is not entirely correct; you would have to make `method_to_extract` a `@staticmethod` if it's inside the `Example` class. Perhaps a better solution then would be to define it outside the class; or define a `@classmethod` which you can call to return a method of that class as an object. But both of these are generally best avoided; your class should probably simply have a method which implements `collect_data`, and your code should simply call that instead.

Comment: Thanks! I agree, the solution is not perfect. However, I can't add a method collect_data to the class, as the code I want to extract the data from is not mine. Ideally, I want to have a class which gets a python file name as an argument, then collects data from the functions in that file, with the file name being variable.

Comment: You know about inheritance, right? You don't need to change the original code, just extend it.

Comment: I considered that, but since I want my code to be flexible and work for any type of python file, I can't extend every single file I want to evaluate.

Comment: @Jakob0403 `any type of python file` I think you have an misunderstanding of Python's module system.