# how to get the function names of a class in Python

Tags: python

```
class CustomETL:

    def func2(df):
        counts.save()

    def extract_and_transform():
        colunas = ['nome', ' idade', ' cpf', ' ativo', ' nascimento', ' estado']
        df = colunas.to_pandas().save().write()
        return df
```

I need to get the names of the functions to have a return as below:

```
func2, extract_and_transform
```

Comment: Please research your inquiry before posting here in accordance with [ask]; this is a duplicate of [How do I get list of methods in a Python class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911281/how-do-i-get-list-of-methods-in-a-python-class)

Comment: You're probably falling in a problem and thought this would be your solution, I recommend talking about your problem directly instead of asking about the solution you've figured out, this we you can get the most benefit

Comment: try `dir(CustomETL)`

Comment: Use dir(object) and object.__dict__ to get all methods and attributes of a class.