# Assigning a class method from a string

Tags: python

I have a class that, when called, forms a connection to a database and enters some data into it. This class is passed to other objects in my program. But I want to test other functionality of my program without having to write to the database every time.

My solution is to make a dummy class that has the same methods as the primary class but which doesn't actually talk to a database. That way all the other objects in the program can still keep their same functionality but I'll have "disconnected" the database read/write options. If there's an alternative way to do what I'm doing, I'd love to be informed of a best practice.

So I want to create a dummy class that has all the same methods as another class but with no functionality. For example, if I had the following class:

```py
class Primary:
   def foo(self, a, b):
      return a+b
   def bar(self, a, b):
      return a-b
```

I want the dummy class to be:

```py
class Dummy:
   def foo(self, a, b):
      pass
   def bar(self, a, b):
      pass
```

Is there a way to dynamically access all the method names in `Primary` and use them to create their dummy alternatives in `Dummy`? I could do this manually, but I'd love for `Dummy` to update automatically whenever I add new methods to `Primary`.

My first idea was to assign methods based on a variable, something like:

```py
class Dummy:
   def __init__(self):
      method_list = [func for func in dir(Primary) if callable(getattr(Primary, func)) and not func.startswith("__")]
      for m in method_list:
         self.m = dummy_func

   def dummy_func(self, *args): 
       pass
```

The idea for getting the methods from Primary comes from this question: [How do I get list of methods in a Python class?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39061905/15496939)

But of course you can't assign a method based on a variable (or can you?). I was also wondering if there was a way for `Dummy` to inherit `Primary` but manually overwrite all of its methods, but haven't figured out a way to do that yet.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `[x for x in dir(Primary) if '__' not in x]`? But if you just want to do testing, Jon's comment is far better.

Comment: [`Mock(spec=Primary)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock)? Either use it (as it sounds like you're creating a test double) or look at how it works.

Comment: Mock is a good suggestion. I wasn't aware of that, but it does seem to have the right functionality, though I'm not only using this for testing. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: You should not be using `dir(Primary)`, rather, use `vars` then you can use `for name, attribute in vars(Primary).items(): ... `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like there is `getattr`, there is [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr).

It would probably be better to set the attributes on the `Dummy` class rather than on its instances, to make it match its behaviour more closely.

For example:

```
class Dummy:
   def dummy_func(self, *args): 
       pass

for attr in dir(Primary):
   if callable(getattr(Primary, attr)) and not attr.startswith("__"):
       setattr(Dummy, attr, Dummy.dummy_func)
```

As @jonrsharpe pointed out in a comment, if this is used for testing, you might prefer [`Mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#the-mock-class) instead.

Comment: The key here (which I should have realized) is that setattr doesn't just update predefined attributes, it assigns the value, which creates the attribute if it didn't exist previously.

Comment: don't use `dir`, use `vars(Primary)`

Comment: `vars` would miss inherited methods, which may or may not be what is required. But yes, in cases where `Primary` doesn't have non-`object` superclasses or if you do not want to mock inherited methods, replace `for attr in dir(Primary):` with `for attr, value in vars(Primary).items()` and `getattr(Primary, attr)` with `value`.